# Convert Speeach of any language into the text in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have seen some links like http://techtalk-java.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-implement-voice-android.html  but they only convert the meaning full words like Hello or Good Morning etc.

But if i Speak like name of any person then it is unable to do that. Like i pronounce "Salman Khan" and it is giving me "mine con".

So how can i convert any speech into the text.

Comment: This is not possible. Take for example the word "hat" in english. If pronounced, this would simply be written "hat" if the speech recognition would be set to english. However, if the speech recognition is set to dutch, it will write down "het" due to the way the "a" pronounced in english is similar to the way the "e" is pronounced in dutch. So no matter what, you'll first need to set the speech recognition to some language for it to make sense.

Comment: Quite difficult task. Consider how many languages are there[6000 I think?], and consider that each language has thousands of terms, and other thousands of names for persons/places etc. 
So you have hundred of millions, or billions of "words". Many of which are pronounced the same but have completely different meanings or transcription for the different languages.
It's simply impossible to have speech-to-text for _all_ . You can handle _some_ languages, and even then you can't expect to have a list of _all_ names ever used.
So there is no hope for an answer. Specify what exactly you want.

Comment: @nightcracker so i have to choose only two or three languages in which i can convert the speech into the text.

Answer (score 1):

You convert the speech in to text for specific words because from where ever your program getting the words are limited or few words are getting hard coded. As your Salman Khan is not in your list of word, so your program show word quite similar to it. For better result pass more words, you will get more output.

Comment: ok vikas i will try to add the words. But we can not convert the speech into the text for any language this is clear. We can do this for a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is helpful.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/free-hands-speechtotext-android/